# Comparing two times for equality within tolerance?

Tags: c++, windows, time, timer

I have an MFC application where I want a certain method to be called at specified times.  I will specify the times by using a vector of tm structs that have the hour minute and second filled out.  Possibly I may need to store a boolean value for each time to indicate whether the method was called at the specified time.  I have a timer that goes off every 50ms.

In MFC, the time is not guaranteed to go off at the specified interval.  I want to ensure that the method is called even if off by a few seconds.  My application does not currently require precise timing (although I'm open to it if there is an easy solution).  My current thought on how to do this is to allow for some slippage such that I allow the time to be equal +/- a few seconds.  Does that seem like a reasonable way to achieve this?

I want to check if two times are equal within a certain tolerance of seconds.  What's the best way to to this in c++?  I have access to a CTime object and/or a struct tm object (and potentially other windows time data structures)

**UPDATE**

I guess there is actually added complexity in the case where the seconds is near the minute or hour boundary.  I can't just compare seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [mktime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/mktime/) to get a `time_t`.  `time_t` is generally the number of seconds since the beginning of 1970, so you don't need to worry about 2:10:59 vs 2:11:01.

```
struct tm expected_tm;
struct tm actual_tm;

// set those tms to something

time_t expected_time = mktime( &expected_tm );
time_t actual_time = mktime( &actual_tm );

if ( abs( expected_time - actual_time ) < 5 ) // for 5s tolerance
{
    // GOOD
}
else
{
     // BAD
}
```

Comment: I like this my only hesitation at the moment is that it's sensitive to the date not just the time.  So I have to make expected time's date is always the same as actual times date.  In practice it probably won't come up because the application will typically be shutdown between days.  Although conceptually I'm still wondering how to achieve date independence.

Comment: I guess I can just set the year, month, and day on the struct tm's to be the same.  Based on your answer I decided to create a vector of time_t's instead of a vector of struct tm but I if go back to struct tm's then it looks like I can set the date pretty easily.

Comment: The other thing is I'd like it to be the expected time or greater.  This will actually attempt to start 5 seconds before the expected time if possible.